# Improve Cypress structure and reuse Given step in multiple files

Tags: reactjs, cucumber, cypress

I am using Cypress and Cucumber for my end to end test.

I have the following Cypress structure:

```
page-one/
another-page/
cypress/integration/page-one/check-hero.js
cypress/integration/page-one/check-custom-block.js
cypress/integration/page-one.feature
cypress/integration/another-page.feature
```

Inside both files `check-hero.js` and `check-custom-block.js` I have:

```
Given('I navigate to page one', () => {
  cy.visit(`${Cypress.env('baseUrl')}/page-one`);
});
```

Can I improve this structure to make it more DRY and to reuse this Given step in multiple files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create reusable step definitions as they call it in the official docs for [cypress-cucumber-preprocessor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor).

You can create a file in `cypress/integration/common/` with your `Given` step and then use it in both `cypress/integration/page-one/check-hero.js` and `cypress/integration/page-one/check-custom-block.js`. If I understand the documentation well, the file with reusable steps can have really any name, let's say `visit.js` in your example.

Comment: thanks! Inside `cypress/integration/common/` I created a file `navigate.js`. Image I have another `.feature` 'another-page.feature'. In here I have also some steps which can reuse some logic. In this feature I have to navigate to another url. Can I simply add another `Given` to `navigate.js`, like `Given('I navigate to another page', () => {
  cy.visit(`${Cypress.env('baseUrl')}/another-page`);
});`. Is this a good pattern/practice?

Comment: @meez: yes, that sounds like a good idea. steps you want to use in multiple feature files can go to the common directory.

Answer (score 0):

Please use Cypress Commands for re-use [link](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands#Parent-Commands)

Comment: Cypress commands do not solve the situation with reusable step definitions in Cucumber.